# How to edit sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I`m new with wordpress, but I was ask a favour so I want to help.
I have such a pice of code, and display all fine. Thing is, I need to add a diffrent submenu on each page. So I thought about if(current_page == 'page') display bla bla bla...
But in functions.php I found only such a pice of code about sidebar that keep menu:

```
 function wp_hot_kindergarten_widgets_init() {
    global $theme_slug;
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $doc->load(FUNCTIONS_PHP_BASEPATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'theme.xml');
    $doc->normalizeDocument();
    $XTheme     =  $doc->getElementsByTagName( "extension" )->item(0);
    $XPosEL = $XTheme->getElementsByTagName( "positions" )->item(0);
    $XPositions = $XPosEL->getElementsByTagName( "position" );  

    $all_layouts_str = '';

    $XConfig    = $XTheme->getElementsByTagName( "config" )->item(0);  
    $XFDS       = $XConfig->getElementsByTagName( "fields" )->item(0);  
    $XFieldSets = $XFDS->getElementsByTagName( "fieldset" );  
    foreach( $XFieldSets as $XFieldSet ) 
    {
        $XFields = $XFieldSet->getElementsByTagName( "field" );
        foreach( $XFields as $XField){
          if($XField->getAttribute("type") == 'designlayout'){
            $all_layouts_str .= (get_option($theme_slug.'_'.$XField->getAttribute("name")).'  ');
          }
        }
    }

    foreach($XPositions as $XPosition){
        if($XPosition->getAttribute('layout_embeded') == 'true' || strpos(strtolower($all_layouts_str),strtolower($XPosition->nodeValue).'=')){
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => ucfirst($XPosition->nodeValue),
                'id' => strtolower($XPosition->nodeValue),
                'description' =>  $XPosition->getAttribute("description"),
                'before_widget' => $XPosition->getAttribute("before_widget"),
                'after_widget' => $XPosition->getAttribute("after_widget"),
                'before_title' => $XPosition->getAttribute("before_title"),
                'after_title' => $XPosition->getAttribute("after_title")
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

and on the page is shown as:

```
   dynamic_sidebar(ucfirst($mpostion[0]));
```

How should I, or where I could add my if condition? Sorry, but this is my first steps with WordPress, and I lost myself with it.

Comment: Instead of modifying any function, why don't you create different menus from Admin Panel and display accordingly?

Comment: I did! I created menus from admin panel. But all menus are displaying by this function. This function displaying one menu on every page, I`m not able to change it from admin panel. That why I started looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `wp_nav_menu()` function to display menus according to the pages.

```
Eg.
<?php
if (current_page == "xyz") {
    wp_nav_menu( 'menu' => 'xyz-menu' );
}
else if (current_page == "abc") {
    wp_nav_menu( 'menu' => 'abc-menu' );
}
?>
```

where `xyz-menu` and `abc-menu` are the menus that you have created at the back end.